# Add a CSS class from jQuery (both external files)

Tags: jquery, css

How do I add a CSS class (external style sheet) from jQuery (external javascript file)?

Here is my jQuery code:

```
$(this).addClass('myClass');
```

And here is my css code:

```
.myClass{
    background-color: blue;
}
```

Here is my file structure:

```
C:.
└───MyProject
    │   index.html
    │
    ├───resources
    │   ├───css
    │   │       style.css
    │   │
    │   └───js
    │           script.js
    │
    └───vendors
        │
        ├───jquery
        │       jquery-1.11.2.min.js
```

And here is are html link tags:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="resources/css/style.css" />    <script
src="vendors/jquery/jquery-1.11.2.min.js"></script>    <script
src="resources/js/script.js"></script>
```

Comment: To make the link tags display in the question, you need to put a linebreak before the start of the code

Comment: Is your jQuery within a document ready call or at the end of the document?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

it doesnt matter how your file structure is. As long as you are loading your css correctly your style will be applied to your html.

Comment: +1 My styles are already working in the html. However, I created the new class `myClass` above but I'm not able to use it

Comment: @Sparky Try to `console.log($(this));` to see if $(this) is the element you want

Comment: @Sparky or inspect the element you are adding class to. Most likely you are not adding `myClass` to it. Check the console for any errors as well